# Why can `Box<T> where T: Trait` not be passed as a parameter?

Tags: rust

Why does this code fail to compile?

```
trait TFoo {}

fn foo<T: TFoo>(v: Box<T>) {}

fn bar(v: Box<TFoo>) {
    foo(v);
}

fn main() {}
```

compilation error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `TFoo: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     foo(v);
  |     ^^^ `TFoo` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `TFoo`
  = note: required by `foo`
```

This code compiles if the signature of `foo` is `fn foo(v: Box<TFoo>)`. Why can `Box<T> where T: Trait` not be passed as a parameter, but `Box<Trait>` can be passed?

Comment: Didn't you mean `fn bar<T: TFoo>(v: Box<T>)`?

Comment: The other answer doesn't cover the question here, which is why `Box<Trait>` works as a parameter but `Box<TYPE>` doesn't.

Comment: with signature `fn foo<T: TFoo+?Sized>(v: Box<T>)` this code compiled ok

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm not following you. This code is trying to pass a `Box<TFoo>` to a function that accepts a `Box<T>`. This means that `T` must be `TFoo`, which is not sized, but the `T` is `Sized` by default. This **is covered** in the duplicate: *this is popping up because [...] `Fn(&mut Writer) -> IoResult<()>`. If we match this against the `F: Fn(&mut W) -> IoResult<()>` [...] we find that `W = Writer` [...] This is illegal because the `W` parameters in both the trait and the impl are defaulting to have a `Sized` bound, if we manually override it with `?Sized` then everything works fine*.

Comment: @Shepmaster `Box` is ultimately a pointer, so it may not be obvious why `Box` containing an unsized type is itself unsized. (One could imagine `Box<T>` being pointer-sized for any T, like C++'s `unique_ptr<T>`.). The linked answer does not mention `Box` at all.

Comment: @user4815162342 OK, I can fix that.

Comment: @Shepmaster Your other answer still doesn't address why the size of the type is relevant when moving a box. Nor does it need to, because the other question is not specifically about `Box`. Instead of editing the other answer, please reopen this question, so that it can be answered properly.

Comment: @user4815162342 I disagree — both questions are "why does passing a trait object (`&Trait` / `Box<Trait>` / `Rc<Trait>`, etc.) to a function that accepts a generic of the same shape (`&T` / `Box<T>` / `Rc<T>`, etc.) generate a warning about `Sized`". `Box` vs `&` is simply incidental.